# Uncaught TypeError: todos.forEach and todos.push is not a function

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty new to javascript (and to stackoverflow) and have been following an online video tutorial to make a basic JS Todo App.

From what I can see my code is exactly as the tutor has done, but for some reason i'm getting two errors:

`Uncaught TypeError: todos.forEach is not a function`

`Uncaught TypeError: todos.push is not a function`

So, I understand the first function (filterTodo) contains `todos.forEach` which is going to loop over all the todos i've created and the switch statement will check the values associated to those todos and return the corresponding ones.

The other function `saveLocalTodo` contains the array method .push (`todos.push`) which essentially adds any newly created todos, to local storage.

```js
 

// Selectors
const todoInput = document.querySelector('.todo-input');
const todoButton = document.querySelector('.todo-button');
const todoList = document.querySelector('.todo-list');
const filterOption = document.querySelector('.filter-todo');

//Event Listeners
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', getTodos);
todoButton.addEventListener('click', addTodo);
todoList.addEventListener('click', deleteCheck);
filterOption.addEventListener('click', filterTodo);
 

//Functions
function addTodo(event){
    //prevent form submitting
    event.preventDefault();
    
    //Todo Div
    const todoDiv = document.createElement('div');
    todoDiv.classList.add('todo');
    
    // Create LI
    const newTodo = document.createElement('li');
    newTodo.innerText = todoInput.value;
    newTodo.classList.add('todo-item');
    todoDiv.appendChild(newTodo);
    
    // ADD TODO to local storage
    saveLocalTodos(todoInput.value);
    
    //Completed Button
    const completedButton = document.createElement('button');
    completedButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-check"></i>';
    completedButton.classList.add('complete-button');
    todoDiv.appendChild(completedButton);
    
    //Trash Button
    const trashButton = document.createElement('button');
    trashButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-trash"></i>';
    trashButton.classList.add('trash-button');
    todoDiv.appendChild(trashButton);
    
    //Append to list
    todoList.appendChild(todoDiv);

    //Clear Todo Input Value
    todoInput.value = "";
}

//Delete toDo

function deleteCheck(e) {
    const item = e.target;
    //DELETE TODO
    if(item.classList[0] === 'trash-button') {
        const todo = item.parentElement;
        //ANIMATION
        todo.classList.add("fall");
        todo.addEventListener('transitionend', function () {
            todo.remove();
        });
    }

    // CHECK MARK
    if(item.classList[0] ==='complete-button') {
        const todo= item.parentElement;
        todo.classList.toggle('completed');
    }
 
}

function filterTodo(e) {
    const todos = todoList.childNodes;
    todos.forEach(function (todo) {
        switch (e.target.value) {
            case "all":
                todo.style.display = "flex";
                break;
            case "completed":
                if (todo.classList.contains("completed")) {
                    todo.style.display = "flex";
                } else {
                    todo.style.display = "none";
                }
                break;
            case "uncompleted":
                if (!todo.classList.contains("completed")) {
                    todo.style.display = "flex";
                } else {
                    todo.style.display = "none";
                }
                break;
        }
    });
}

function saveLocalTodos(todo){
    // CHECK - Are there already todos created?
    let todos;
    if(localStorage.getItem('todos') === null) {
        todos = [];
    }else{
        todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos'));
    }
    todos.push(todo);
    localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify(todos));
}

function getTodos() {
    // CHECK - Are there already todos created ?
        let todos;
    if (localStorage.getItem('todos') === null) {
        todos = [];
    } else {
        todos = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todos'));
    }
    
    todos.forEach(function(todo) {
        //Todo Div
        const todoDiv = document.createElement('div');
        todoDiv.classList.add('todo');

        // Create LI
        const newTodo = document.createElement('li');
        newTodo.innerText = todo;
        newTodo.classList.add('todo-item');
        todoDiv.appendChild(newTodo);

        //Completed Button
        const completedButton = document.createElement('button');
        completedButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-check"></i>';
        completedButton.classList.add('complete-button');
        todoDiv.appendChild(completedButton);

        //Trash Button
        const trashButton = document.createElement('button');
        trashButton.innerHTML = '<i class="fas fa-trash"></i>';
        trashButton.classList.add('trash-button');
        todoDiv.appendChild(trashButton);

        //Append to list
        todoList.appendChild(todoDiv);
    });
}
```

To me, that all looks ok, but when I run in chrome I get those errors above. I've also run this through a validator and it doesn't throw any errors.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I suspect, being a beginner i'm missing something obvious.

Cheers

Comment: It important to know what `todoList` is. If you make your code more compact you basically say that `todoList.childNodes.forEach(...)` is not working, but haven't given us the definition of `todoList`.

Comment: Hi there, sorry! I've now posted the entire code.

Answer (score 2):

Your `todoList.childNodes` in `filterTodo` as well as `todos` object in `saveLocalTodos` (after being fetched from `localStorage`) are not valid arrays. Since you have not published the full working code, that's all I can infer. Debug those and you will solve the issue.